# Not comfortable with boss

Tags: management

I don't like the the bossy behavior of my CEO, I am working for a very small startup (less then 5 people). He call someone by knocking the glass in the room, does not show a smiling face in the morning and etc - should I leave this company?

(Update: I left this company right before the delta variant spreading)

Comment: If you are miserable, you have no obligation to stay at that company. We can't tell you what you should do with your career -- you would know more than we would what is best for you.

Answer (score 8):

These are small kinds of issues on the surface, yet they seem to indicate that you have a deeper level of dissatisfaction with your current role. What else is happening that would make you feel unsettled with your boss or where you work?

I ask this honestly, because if someone told me they were leaving the company because I didn't smile at them in the mornings, then I would be questioning the validity of this offered reason. I think there are more things going on that are making smaller issues like glass-tapping and non-smiling irritating.

So rather than any of us try to answer the question of "should I leave the company?" which we have absolutely no way of answering for you, perhaps you should instead ask yourself, "Why do these things annoy me so much?"

While it simply *could* be these things bothering you, I strongly suspect that it's something else that is the root cause. Until you can understand the real reason that you are uncomfortable, then you may well find that the same discomfort will follow you to the next role.